# How to populate the Django Model with the data fetched from the external site?

Tags: django, django-models

From the external site thru API, I have fetched the dictionary data that I want to save it to the Django Model.

I have tried to save the data to the Django Model at the `models.py` but failed.

In the `models.py`, I wrote the `def get_save(self, request)` like the following.

```
class AirData(models.Model):
    co = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    no2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    so2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    pm10 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    pm25 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    datatime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    station = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def get_save(self, request):

            url = "http://openapi.airkorea.or.kr/openapi/services/rest/ArpltnInforInqireSvc/getMsrstnAcctoRltmMesureDnsty"

            params = {'stationName': '강남구', 'dataTerm': 'month', 'pageNo': '1', 'numOfRows': '10',
                      '_returnType': 'json', 'ServiceKey': service_key, 'ver': '1.3'}
            airdata_dict = get_airdata(url, service_key, params)

            self.co = airdata_dict['coValue']
            self.save()
```

But the `airdata_dict`, fetched from the url, is not saved to the instance.

Please help me show how to save data in the Model.

---

Based on the suggestions of @HariHaraSudhan, I changed the views.py as follows

```
def get_value(self):
    url = "http://openapi.airkorea.or.kr/openapi/services/rest/ArpltnInforInqireSvc/getMsrstnAcctoRltmMesureDnsty"

    params = {'stationName': '강남구', 'dataTerm': 'month', 'pageNo': '1', 'numOfRows': '10',
              '_returnType': 'json', 'ServiceKey': service_key, 'ver': '1.3'}
    airdata_dict = get_airdata(url, service_key, params)
    airdata_list = airdata_dict['airdata']
    kwargs = dict()
    for data in airdata_list:
        kwargs['station'] = data['stationName']
        kwargs['co'] = data['coValue']
        kwargs['no2'] = data['no2Value']
        kwargs['so2'] = data['so2Value']
        kwargs['o3'] = data['o3Value']
        kwargs['pm10'] = data['pm10Value']
        kwargs['pm2.5'] = data['pm25Value']
        kwargs['time'] = data['dataTime']

    obj = AirData.objects.create(self.kwargs)
```

And the models.py is also changed as:

```
class AirData(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        my_obj = cls(kwargs)
        return my_obj
```

But the error pops up as **AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'kwargs'**.

Comment: how are you calling `get_save()`? Where are you creating the instance? In your method, you're only setting `co`, nothing else. What about the other required attributes like `no2` etc..? Show us what you're doing to see that the data isn't saved.

Comment: The get_save() is not appropriate name. I just used coValue to see if it is working. If it did, I planed to populate other attributes as well. But it did not work.There is no error message but the Model is not populated.

Comment: "is not appro"? I don't understand

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Please read the new comment.

Comment: but you need to show the code where you *call* get_save(). And `print(airdata_dict)` to show what's in the dict.

Comment: I printed airdate_dict['airdate'] and the portion of the output is [{'_returnType': 'json', 'coGrade': '1', 'coValue': '0.7', 'dataTerm': '', 'dataTime': '2019-05-24 24:00', 'no2Value': '0.038', ''o3Value': '0.041', 'pageNo': '1', 'pm10Grade': '3', 'pm10Grade1h': '3', 'pm10Value': '107', 'pm10Value24': '83', 'pm25Grade': '3', 'pm25Grade1h': '3', 'pm25Value': '73', 'pm25Value24': '58'}, ]

Comment: you're creating a `kwargs` variable, so use that, not `self.kwargs`.

Comment: but based on your output you're trying to assign strings to a `DecimalField`. you need to use the right type, so cast your strings to decimal.

Comment: @dirkgrotne, I also tried that one, too. But it came back with the error:  **TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Comment: and you should be doing `Airdata.objects.create(**kwargs)` (and you don't need to `def create()` at all because you're not using that). Also your code only creates one object (the last of the for loop) whereas you probably want to create a new object inside the loop.

Comment: @dirkgroten, create() is located inside the def get_vlaue() no the separate def.

Comment: did you try `Airdata.objects.create(**kwargs)` instead of `Airdata.objects.create(self.kwargs)`?

Comment: @dirkgroten, yes I did but didn't work. Do I need to define the Class before the def get_data?

Comment: "it didn't work" how? error? Never say "it doesn't work", always explain what you see. And `def get_data` isn't anywhere in your code, so what are you talking about?

Comment: @dirkgroten,  TypeError: AirData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'co' . Also I changed the data attribute as kwargs['co'] = float(data['coValue'].strip('"'))

Comment: @dirkgroten. Sorry for the wrong def name. I keep changing the codes so I got confused. I meant def get_value.

Comment: `kwargs['co'] = Decimal(data['coValue'])` not `float`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193897/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-the-truth-will-set-you-free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model method `get_save` should work if:

1. You make sure you cast the strings received by the API (`airdata['coValue']`) to the correct type, e.g. for `co`:

   ```
   self.co = Decimal(airdata['coValue'])
   ```

   Beware also that your dates are strings, so you need to change them to a proper `datetime.datetime` if you're going to assign them.
2. You make sure all required fields are set before saving (`self.no2` is required, so if it's `None`, your model will not save). You should see an error in that case.

An easier way is to create a dictionary of all the correct values, e.g.

```
kwargs['co'] = Decimal(airdata['coValue'])
...
```

and pass it to the `ModelManager`'s `create()` method:

```
MyModel.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

Make sure *all the keys* in the dictionary correspond to fields of your model.

Comment: Thank you, @dirkgroten. I am struggling yet but getting closer to the answer due to you help. I will work on it.

Comment: at last, I managed to make it work though the program may not be the best way. Thank you again.